SQL Oracle adding new rows to CTE
I'm trying to add addition rows to a CTE table using Oracle SQL and I can't quite get it to work. I've read up and it appears using INSERT INTO () is my best option, but I feel I am missing something simple and I am getting a syntax error at 'Insert'.
Below is the code I'm trying to insert, I have several CTEs above this point (ie. WITH table as (), table2 as (), table3 as (), etc.) but below is the section I'm getting my error:
region as (
select City, County
from clarity_pos cp
left join zc_county zc on zc.county_c = cp.county_c
where cp.county_c is not null
)

Insert into 
region (City, County) 
Values
('AMSTON', 'TOLLAND')
,('BURLINGTON', 'HARTFORD')
,('COVENTRY', 'TOLLAND')
,('DARIAN', 'FAIRFIELD')
,('EAST LYME', 'NEW LONDON')

Select City, County
from region


You can't insert into the cte. You can add another cte query, and do UNION ALL.

This type of insert statement is supported as long as the DB version is 23c+

Please provide sample input data and the expected result

I was beginning to think the same thing, that you can't insert into a CTE. Is this Oracle specific or can you do this using SQL Server?

@BarbarosÖzhan Interesting. Any doc link / fiddle?

@WilliamRobertson https://dbfiddle.uk/p_8-aZ_p ✅ but https://dbfiddle.uk/HslskzRp ❌

@BarbarosÖzhan Ah, you were referring to the new multi-row values syntax. I thought maybe there was something new with CTEs in 23c. Thanks though.

no worries at all @WilliamRobertson

Leave REGION CTE's code as is, and then add additional rows by unioning them, e.g.
 WITH
 region AS
 (
-- original code
          SELECT    city,
                    county
          FROM      clarity_pos cp
          left join zc_county zc
          ON        zc.county_c = cp.county_c
          WHERE     cp.county_c IS NOT NULL
-- now add additional rows:
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'AMSTON',
                 'TOLLAND'
          FROM   dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'BURLINGTON',
                 'HARTFORD'
          FROM   dual )
SELECT city,
       county
FROM   region 


I was thinking of doing something similar to this, however, I have already used 'FROM dual' earlier in my query, my question is only showing a section of a much longer query. I used FROM dual earlier to set a date range, am I able to use dual again?

You can use FROM DUAL as many times as you want within a select. It's very common to generate many dummy rows by unioning individual SELECT ... FROM DUAL statements

I am basing my understanding on the question header, if you want to add additional rows to CTE, you would want something like below, let me know if thats what you want to do.
WITH region AS (
    SELECT City, County
    FROM clarity_pos cp
    LEFT JOIN zc_county zc ON zc.county_c = cp.county_c
    WHERE cp.county_c IS NOT NULL
)
-- Add the additional rows to the result of the CTE using UNION ALL
SELECT City, County
FROM region
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AMSTON', 'TOLLAND' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BURLINGTON', 'HARTFORD' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'COVENTRY', 'TOLLAND' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DARIAN', 'FAIRFIELD' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EAST LYME', 'NEW LONDON' FROM DUAL;


I think this might work, it's longer and more tedious than I was hoping for because I need to add more rows than I listed above, but if this works, I'm fine with that. I will give it a try, thank you!

Ok sure let us know how you find it

Note that this syntax only works from Oracle 23 onwards. Any earlier versions (probably still the vast majority) need SELECT ... FROM DUAL instead of just SELECT .... OP stated this is Oracle

Yes in that case I believe we need to include dual for the previous versions

Thanks @KoenLostrie, I have edited to include DUAL :)
